# ntegrityError NOT NULL constraint failed Request Method:POST

Tags: django

I have this function in my views. which worked on django 1.9

```
def post_create(request):
    form = PostForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        print(form.cleaned_data.get("title"))
        instance.save()
    context = {
        "form": form,
    }
    return render(request, "post_form.html", context)
```

url.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.post_list),
    url(r'^create/$', views.post_create),
    url(r'^(?P<id>\d+)/$', views.post_detail, name='detail'),
    url(r'^update/$', views.post_update),
    url(r'^delete/$', views.post_delete)
]
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse


class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    content = models.TextField()
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("posts:detail", kwargs={"id": self.id})
```

but this is what I get when I wrote it on django 1.10 :

> IntegrityError at /posts/create/
>   NOT NULL constraint failed: posts_post.updated
>   Request Method: POST

any ideas?

Comment: how does the corresponding route in `urls.py` looks like?

Comment: Please show more information, full stack trace, models etc..

Comment: the code is from this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KbOei4IRinc

Comment: Change `if form.is_valid():` to `if request.method =="POST" and form.is_valid():`

Comment: still same problem  karthikr

Comment: Looks like your `PostForm` didn't populate the `Post.updated` field. If it's intentional to leave blank for that field, add a parameter `null=True` to the `DateTimeField` and apply that change to your database.

Comment: it is funny how I got frustrated while the the error is that clear. thank you Mr Philip. you were the reason why I learnt something new today. Thank you sir.